# Spring.net + ASP.NET MVC 3 + PostgreSQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, spring.net, postgresql-8.4

I'm trying to combine `sprig.net` with `ASP.NET MVC3`, using PostgreSQL as DB. I succeeded to do this with MySQL before. Here are my 2 config files:

1) web.config:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="spring">
<section name="parsers" type="Spring.Context.Support.NamespaceParsersSectionHandler,     Spring.Core" />
<section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
<section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler, Spring.Web" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<!-- spring context -->
<spring>
<parsers>
<parser type="Spring.Data.Config.DatabaseNamespaceParser, Spring.Data" />
</parsers>
<context>
<resource uri="~/spring-dao.xml" />
</context>
</spring>
....
```

2) spring-dao.xml (for MySQL DB) was:

```
 <db:provider id="DbProvider" provider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
 ConnectionString="Server=localhost;Database=db_movies;Uid=root;Pwd=1234;"/>
 <object id="SessionFactory" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject,
 Spring.Data.NHibernate32">
 <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/> ...
```

NB: I've referenced the Npgsql.dll.

Do I need another .DLL and how can I change the `<db:provider .../>` to use Postgres as provider?

I looked for examples or tutorials via google, but I didn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

Find below a working configuration of NHibernate32 and Npgsql-2.0 (2.0.11.92) for Spring.Net 1.3.2:

```xml
<db:provider id="PqSqlDbProvider" provider="Npgsql-2.0" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=nhibernate;Password=123456789;Database=Xxxxxxxx;" />

<object name="SessionFactory" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject, Spring.Data.NHibernate32" dependency-check="none">
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="PqSqlDbProvider"/>
  <property name="ExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory" value="true" />
  <property name="MappingAssemblies">
    <list>
      <value>Xxxxxxxx</value>
    </list>
  </property>

  <property
    name="HibernateProperties">
    <dictionary>        
      <entry key="connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
      <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.NpgsqlDriver" />
      <entry key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
      <entry key="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </dictionary>
  </property>
</object>

<object
  name="HibernateTransactionManager"
  type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, Spring.Data.NHibernate32"
  dependency-check="none">
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="PqSqlDbProvider"/>
  <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
</object>

<!-- Attribute driven transaction manager. -->
<tx:attribute-driven transaction-manager="HibernateTransactionManager"/>
```

You also need to amend the `web.config` to load the proper .dll instead of the one referenced by Spring:

```xml
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="2.0.11.92" />
    </dependentAssembly>      
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Hi AndreasKI. Thank you for your answer. I've updated my web.config and spring-dao.xml as you suggest. but i'm facing a new error : **Resource handler for the 'web' protocol is not defined.** when i try to call ContextRegistry.GetContext(); Here is the line that causes error : `IMovieServices service = (IMovieServices)ContextRegistry.GetContext().GetObject("MovieService");`

Comment: This is the **MovieService** declaration in the spring-dao.xml : `<object id="MovieService" type="MvcTest.Services.MovieServicesImpl, MvcTest" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="HibernateTemplate" ref="HibernateTemplate"/>
  </object>`

Comment: When do you call `IMovieServices service = (IMovieServices)ContextRegistry.GetContext().GetObject("MovieService");`? Imho the context is not ready e.g. you are calling before Application (global.asax) `Init` is executed. Anyway you should not directly access the Context. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807355/iis-server-and-spring-net-object-instantiation-failed

Comment: Hi AndreasKI. Thank you for your answer. I use this call in a controller. I never initialized the context manually. By adding the IIS 7 config, as explained in the thread above(that you gave me), all went fine. It works now, despite i've IIS 8.0 installed !! THANK U A LOT !!

Comment: @IbrahimaMouctarDiallo: If Andreas' answer solved your question, please consider *accepting* it. [More info here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)